# Что такое додекальон?

Tags: значение-слов

Что такое додекальон?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это единица с 39 нулями. Образовано от греческого додека - 12 и суффикса -льон. Иронически  слово используется для обозначения до невозможности большого количества чего-либо.
Выглядит число следующим образом:

1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000

Comment: Словом *додекамерон* можно обозначить экранизацию Доде Камероном)))

Comment: Вообще-то суффикс *-льон* мне совсем не нравится. Во-первых, он суффикс наверняка не русскоязычный. Т.е. в русском языке этот элемент будет почти наверняка частью корня. Во-вторых, лучше *-лион*. Ср. разг. "*мульён*", "*мильон*" и "*миллион*", "*биллион*", "*триллион*" и т.д.

Поэтому пока не плюсую.

Comment: @gecube, миллион и миллиард случай особый, а остальные числа представляют собой латинский корень и суффикс -(и)ллион или -(и)льон. Причем последний распространен даже шире, по крайне мере квадриллион и квадрильон словари дают как равнозначные слова.

При желании додекальон можно называть доудециллион, но в "Занимательной физике" Перельмана дан вариант через -льон.

Comment: 1. Наверное, не доудециллион, а дуодециллион.
2. Перельман - это книжка советской эпохи. Тогда и идеология была, что в СССР все свое было, так и ученый Полинг появился (вместо Паулинга).
3. Вы не указали, что в англоязычных странах используется две шкалы. Понятно, что к России это отношение имеет косвенное, но трудности перевода случаются, т.к. в совр. английском миллиард называется биллионом и дальше идет смещение числовых значений. См. [Вики][1]

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers

Comment: С Англией и США расхождение только в названии миллиарда. Отличия есть с континентальной Европой, но как вы верно заметили, для русского языка это малозначимо. Также малозначимо и то, какие тенденции в названии чисел у математиков, если слово уже закрепилось, а закрепилось оно, по всей видимости, именно благодаря Перельману. На практике додекальоном всё равно никто не пользуется и звучание термина имеет лишь сугубо академическое значение.

Comment: @Марк Из, ну, если посмотреть внимательнее, то Duodecillion (дуодециллион) может обозначать как 10^39, так и 10^72. Я так думаю, что в художественной литературы эти слова просто будут употребляться как синонимы очень большого количества, а в научном тексте лучше пользоваться стандартной записью или через единицы СИ с нужными приставками, или научной записью чисел вида mantissa * 10^exponenta

Comment: @gecube, по-французски или немецки -да, может обозначать и 10^72, но насколько знаю ни немцы, ни французы кириллицу для письма не используют, а там где кириллицей пользуются считают все исключительно по короткой шкале. Поэтому, если увидели "додекальон", написанный русскими буквами, это или 10^39, или синоним выражения "до фига". Если же написано латиницей "duodecillion", то тогда уже надо смотреть контекст.

Comment: @Марк Из, в принципе согласен, но все равно стоит обратить внимание, что эти слова такие... непростые. "Ложные друзья переводчика".

Answer (score 0):

Существует ли такой суффикс - "льон"?